# Javascript error when inserting code with <script> into an iFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm trying to insert the html content in a few iFrames and I got a strange javascript error when I'm adding a   tag. The code I want to insert looks like (on the real example there is some code) :

```
<head>
  <script>/*This line is causing the problem */</script>
</head>
<body>   
  <h1 style='text-align: center;'>This IS an iframe</h1>
</body>
```

the js errror is : Uncaught TypeError: **Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null**  (you need to be in development mode). If you remove the  line the error will not longer exist.

The simplified source code example: 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MdoLpq

I'm a bit lost here, any ideas or hints are welcomed.

Comment: @RandyCasburn, mate don't be to lazy ...

Comment: Me? Post your code with your question - don't be lazy!

Comment: You don't see the codepen link? : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MdoLpq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure jQuery strips out `<script>` tags when using the `.html()` method. To get around this use plain javascript `.innerHTML`.

For example, instead of..

```
$("#1").contents().find('html').html( frameCode );
```

Replace with this...

```
$("#1").contents().find('html').get(0).innerHTML = frameCode;
```